# Requisição cross-origin bloqueada - JS/CORS/AXIOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, post, axios

Estou usando uma API (Axios) para conectar o backend da minha aplicação ao frontend, no entanto, não estou conseguindo dar POST (cadastrar um novo registro) em uma das páginas pois o Mozilla Firefox bloqueia requisições cross-origin.
Dei uma pesquisada na internet, entendi o porquê do problema mas não entendi ainda como resolvê-lo usando JavaScript e a API.

A mensagem do erro:

> Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em http://localhost:3333/ongs. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente).

(O meu frontend está rodando em http://localhost:3000/register)

Segue o código da API:

```
export default function Register(){
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [whatsapp, setWhatsapp] = useState('');
const [city, setCity] = useState('');
const [uf, setUf] = useState('');

async function handleRegister(e){ //função que será executada a todo submit
    e.preventDefault(); //Evita que o form recarregue a cada submit

    const data = {
        name,
        email,
        whatsapp,
        city,
        uf,
    };

    try{

        const response = await api.post('ongs', data); //por padrão, o axios já envia pro backend em formato json
        alert(`Seu ID de acesso: ${response.data.id}`);
    }catch (err){
        alert('Erro no cadastro, tente novamente.');
    }
}

return (inputs aqui);
```

Como já disse antes, percebi que esse erro é associado à ausência do `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=true` no header da requisição, mas como eu faço isso?

Comment: Não, pois no link só explicam como se faz em Swift e Php (ou usando o Chrome diretamente), no meu caso, estou usando o Firefox e estava procurando a solução equivalente em JS.

Comment: Apesar do bloqueio ser feito no navegador, a configuração deve ser feita no servidor. Deve-se configurar os cabeçalhos independente da linguagem que vc vai (está) usa(ndo). Apesar da possibilidade de desabilitar o CORS no navegador, é inviável você forçar seus clientes a fazê-la. Ou é? Veja se alguma dessas [perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cross+origin) te atende...

Comment: Sim, é inviável. O único jeito seria configurando na própria aplicação mesmo, setando os headers, mas não sei como fazê-lo usando JS (node/axios).

Answer (score 1):

A configuração do cors deve ser feita no backend para acesso de seus endpoints. Não sei como foi feito seu backend... Porém, segue um exemplo utilizando-se de Node e Express:

Antes, deve-se adicionar a dependêcia cors;

```
npm install cors
```

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors()); // habilitando o cors da aplicação para todas as rotas

app.listen(8081, () => {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 8081')
})
```

Não sei se foi útil, porém essa seria uma implementação em Node... Espero ter ajudado :)